# Передал свой автопортрет" - есть ли плеоназм?

Tags: стилистика

Как-то на упражнениях по культуре речи у меня вышел спор с преподавательницей. Я считал, что во фразе "**художник передал свой автопортрет музею**" избыточности нет, так как у художника мог быть, например, автопортрет ван Гога, и без уточнения "свой" предложение становится недосказанным. Если же убрать приставку авто-, то непонятно, что на портрете изображён именно сам художник.

А что по этому поводу думаете вы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, тут "свой" может означать, что он автопортрет никому не подарил, и он до момента передачи музею принадлежал автору. Тогда слово "свой" оправдано. А если "свой" употреблено для определения лица на портрете, то, конечно, плеоназм.

Answer (score 1):

если слово "свой" не убирать из предложения ,а автопортрет не этого художника,то надо уточнить чей автопортрет.

Comment: Я в принципе соглашусь с @Таня 35. Портрет - это, скажем, жанр изобразительного искусства. А автопортрет - его разновидность (т.е. художник изобразил самого себя). При этом автопортрет может быть чужой - в смысле принадлежит другому человеку или на на автопортрет был создан другим человеком и там изображен этот другой человек.
Может я немного криво объяснил свою позицию, но, думаю, меня можно вполне понять.